# 1960s British comic story

Tags: story-identification

This question is probably unanswerable but I'll ask it anyway. In the mid-60s my best friend visited the UK and came back with a book made up of both written and comic book-style SF stories. It was a hardback, rather worn (it might have been used even then) and was about the size of a coffee-table book. I can remember just one line - the first line - from just one story: 'In the apartment a piano was playing a man'. That's all. If anyone can answer this I will give them my first-born child.

Comment: Maybe try searching for "In a room in a tower, high above the city, a piano was playing a man."?  Christopher Priest remembers a story starting that way.

Comment: https://www.tor.com/2016/09/19/five-sci-fi-books-that-make-use-of-music/

Comment: Your description reminds me of a British "Annual". Very popular until recently, hardback, larger than A4, often based on a weekly comic, or popular TV show(eg Star Trek, Dr. Who), often included a mixture of articles, comic strips, and short fiction. If you look at Google image results of British Annual books, you can see if they look similar to what you remember.

Comment: Why is this attracting close votes? It seems a perfectly good question to me. It feels like J. G. Ballard from his Vermillion Sands or The Four-Dimensional Nightmare era, though I have checked all the Ballard stories I have and none match.

Comment: Martin: it definitely was a British annual. At first I thought of Dan Dare (I'm pretty sure there was a space ship on the cover), then realized Christopher Priest would have remembered that. Well, it may have the word 'Boy's' or 'Adventure' in the title, so I will keep looking.

Comment: I have found that looking through eBay for Bumper Books (that's what a lot of these were called) from the appropriate time period is a decent way to locate something like this book.  The pictures of covers can trigger immediate recognition.  I've had luck with it.

Comment: Thanks to you all for your help - the only British comic I am familiar with is 'Commando'. Christopher Priest said he was 13 when he got the book, so that is a starting point. Thanks again.

Comment: I think some of us were hoping it was _New Worlds_, but the hardback thing rules that out.

Comment: Priest was 13 in 1956, so the book my friend had was used or a reprint. Did these annuals do reprints?

Comment: @Lee Eckhardt Did your story also contain a remark such as "In such circumstances, the proverb 'Don't shoot the pianist, he's only doing his best' took on a new meaning"? This because the piano was somehow electronically linked to the pianist? Other things: if it's the book I'm thinking of, one story (possibly the same) mentioned a man who "had more degrees than a thermometer". One character may have been Farquhar or Urquehart. The pages might have been coarse texture, and the covers quite thick. The piano story may have involved a vast time lapse, over 1 million years.

Comment: @Lee Eckhardt I wonder whether my author was A. E. van Vogt. My story struck me as being more complex, and more SF-aware, than the average hack for a children's annual might produce. (Perhaps that's unfair: I don't know how authors were found.) And while van Vogt had his problems ( https://thefinchandpea.com/2013/01/14/the-infuriating-and-essential-science-fiction-of-a-e-van-vogt/ ), his stories were complex as I remember this one being. The vast time lapse is also a clue, having emotional impact but no validity, since objects would have decayed. Only relevant if our stories _are_ the same.

Comment: @Lee Eckhardt "Did these annuals do reprints?". They hang around in attics and second-hand shops. Used ones would have been available for years then and are now. I can still buy annuals even from the 1930's — indeed, I have some *Greyfriars Holiday Annual*s from the 1920's — and do, for the artwork.

Comment: @John Rennie As I hope I've demonstrated, the question is perfectly good. If the story I remember reading is the same as Lee's, it was good SF, intelligently written, definitely within the ambit of this group. I do find, though, that some users like closing questions rather than helping the asker. I saw this on Cross Validated, where someone asked for an explanation of quadratic Bézier curves, and several people voted to close. What I did was to write an R program that answered their question, relate it to available online equations, then post the graphs and other results. Much more helpful.

Comment: To all: I certainly appreciate your help in this matter. The only things I can remember is the story's first line, the illustration that went with the story (featuring the man at the piano), and the cover, which think had a space ship on it. As far as the author goes Christopher Priest (his memory seems slightly better than mine) said the story was unsigned, so there is no way to tell if was von Vogt or not. Although, now that you mention it, it does seem rather his style...

Comment: I remember this story from my late 50s/early 60s boyhood when I had a copy of this book; I too can't remember title or author. However I remember that the hero had a short name like ZTL, and was in a position of authority. I seem to remember that there was a space battle culminating in one of his subordinates known as the 'Milit-Ant Harmost' sacrificing himself & his spacecraft to save 'ZTL' & win the battle. The story ended with the piano playing ZTL again whilst he reflected on the turn of events & wondering if the new Milit-Ant Harmost would be as good...

Comment: After the opening sentence, the story went on to say that the piano liked playing him due to his various fine qualities, and that it could be highly dangerous with risk of injury if an unsuitable person attempted to play.

Comment: I've got enough kids thanks.